# Passing textFielddata with prepareForSegue as a number and not a string

Tags: xcode, string, swift, xcode6, numbers

I am having trouble with the whole string int thing.

I have managed to figure out how to convert each string to a number, however it returns as an optional and when I try to do anything with it I get nil.

My goal is to take 4 inputs from the user.

Each input textField is on separate view controllers.

Each view controller is fed data from variables passed from the view controller before it, using segue  prepareForSegue.

Now I get to the last view controller and all the data passes fine, the problem is I cannot do any math with the values held in the variables since they are Strings.

Even after doing the conversion with `.int()` I cannot do math with them.

This is the last view controller classfile code:

```
class splitTheBillAmountViewController: UIViewController {

 // capture passed data from previous View Controller

    var numOfGuests = ""    
    var subTotalAmount = ""    
    var taxAmount = ""    
    var tipAmount = ""    

    @IBOutlet weak var dynamicTotal: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {    
        super.viewDidLoad()            
        println("Split The Bill!”)        

// output variables data

       println(numOfGuests)    
        println(subTotalAmount)    
        println(taxAmount)   
        println(tipAmount)

// store variables to new name

        let string1 = numOfGuests    
        let string2 = subTotalAmount    
        let string3 = taxAmount    
        let string4 = tipAmount

// conversions

        let guestNumber : Int? = string1.toInt()    
        let subTotalNumber : Int? = string2.toInt()    
        let taxAmountNumber : Int? = string3.toInt()    
        let tipNumber : Int? = string4.toInt()

// visual to see if numbers are converted .int()

        println("\(guestNumber)")    
        println("\(subTotalNumber)")    
        println("\(taxAmountNumber)")    
        println("\(tipNumber)")

// store data to variable

        let fTotal : Int? = (guestNumber)

// Update label with total

        self.dynamicTotal.text = “fTotal"

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.    
    }
```

How can I do math with these variables?

I just need to add them up and divide by var numOfGuests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you want to use Ints for all these values, but that aside I ran this code:

```
var numOfGuests = "2"
var subTotalAmount = "25"
var taxAmount = "3"    
var tipAmount = "2"

let string1 = numOfGuests
let string2 = subTotalAmount
let string3 = taxAmount    
let string4 = tipAmount

let guestNumber : Int? = string1.toInt()
let subTotalNumber : Int? = string2.toInt()
let taxAmountNumber : Int? = string3.toInt()    
let tipNumber : Int? = string4.toInt()

println("\(guestNumber)")    
println("\(subTotalNumber)")    
println("\(taxAmountNumber)")    
println("\(tipNumber)")
```

it printed:

Optional(2)

Optional(25)

Optional(3)

Optional(2)

I then modified the print statements to:

```
    println("\(guestNumber!)")

    println("\(subTotalNumber!)")

    println("\(taxAmountNumber!)")

    println("\(tipNumber!)")
```

It printed:

2

25

3

2

In neither case was the output nil.  I think you want to look at how your original strings are getting set.  Maybe they're never getting reset from "".

BTW, back to the use of Int types for the calculations, I think you really want to use Float type, not Int.

This code:

```
var subTotalAmount = "25.15"
let string2 = subTotalAmount
var subTotalNumber = (string2 as NSString).floatValue
println("\(subTotalNumber)")
```

prints:

25.15

EDIT:

I played with copying your code, and I think you know that you have a typo that the compiler should warn you about.  Once I fixed the typo, however I was getting a nil.  I got this code to work:

```
var subTotalAmount = "25.15"
let string2 = subTotalAmount
var subTotalNumber = (string2 as NSString).floatValue
println("\(subTotalNumber)")

let text = NSString(format: "%.2f", subTotalNumber)
println(text)
```

This prints:

25.15

25.15

EDIT2:

Assuming you have all the numbers as floats, the total bill would be:

```
var fTotal:Float = subTotalNumber + taxAmountNumber + tipNumber
var costPerGuest:Float = fTotal / guestNumber

let fTotalText = NSString(format: "%.2f", fTotal)
let costPerGuestText = NSString(format: "%.2f", costPerGuest)
```

Comment: WOW thanks so much! I will test that out. Yea I am new to swift and still understanding all the possibilities and elements, thats where my mind was able to get to lol Ill be back with results thanks so much!

Comment: This is awesome I was able to get it to output the numbers for the other variables too! Now i gotta figure out how to add them all up! LOL Thank you sir!

Comment: You should have all the numbers now as floats...the math should be a cinch.  Glad I could help.

Comment: hmmm you would think it'd be a cicnh, but i guess im retarded. I get errors...  It is just concatenating and not doing math to get a sum... I ust be missing something as I hve read every opertor and operand site on it. i already tried multiple options. the closest I get is with:  let fTotal = text1 + text2
        self.dynamicTotal.text = fTotal  but concatonates to 5.00.5.00. My head must be stuck on javascript. I can tell transitioning is going to be a pain for me. it took me2  years to get JavaScript LOL

Comment: Awesome! More testing!! =) thanks dude! i owe you a drink! lol

Comment: Thanks.  I told you the math would be a cinch.

Comment: I feel like I should offer you something (the old italian in me). I cooka you summa pasta huh?

Comment: Maybe if you ever get to Bangkok.

Comment: Actually, you haven't accepted the answer; you could do that.

Comment: HAHA sorry I am new to Stack Overflow! I accepted! and hey ya never kno, i just might =P

Comment: Please be sure to let me know if you plan to come here.  This is not a place for newbies on their own.